# Did Jesse James ever take part in a duel?

Tags: old-west

We all know that Jesse James was an American outlaw and bank, train and stagecoach robber. He lived in the mid to late 1800s, and things were different back then than they are today. One way of settling an argument or dispute was participating in a duel. A duel is a contest with deadly weapons (usually a firearm), arranged between two people in order to settle a point of honor. Jesse James killed approximately 20 people while he robbed, and I am lead to think that surely at one point during his career as a robber that he participated in a duel. So my question is: Did Jesse James ever take part in a duel with another person?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I have searched all over the internet, and read a few magazines, and I haven't found anything about Jesse James taking part in a duel.

Comment: That information should be part of the question; most SE sites expect the research to be part of the question, and my experience is that people don't read the comments.

Comment: I'd also challenge the framing of the question: Hollywood-style gunfights may have (almost) never happened in the authentic West, making it even less likely James was ever in one.

Comment: @jeffronicus - Yes, but … they *did* happen, were more common among southerners (like James), and in fact the first recorded one happened in Springfield Missouri, which is pretty much the James Gang's stomping ground. So it *is* a possibility (although one where it would be fair to presume negatively in the absence of evidence).